# How do I make a valid multiline Javascript REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of text that can literally be anything. Somewhere in the text is something like [block] or [header]. I want to match against the following regex:

`new RegExp("(.*)\\[" + config.wrapper+ "\\](.*)", "m");`

If I write "hello[block]" it works perfect.

If I write "hello

[block]" it catches nothing.

What am I missing to properly match?

Note, for complicated reasons, I can't currently use a template engine like handlebars or any of those in this special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
(.*)
```

to this:

```
([\\s\\S]*)
```

because the `.` doesn't match line breaks.

Comment: `pattern = new RegExp( "([\s\S]*)\\[" + config.wrapper+ "\\](.*)", "m" );` made it stop detecting everything somehow. I also tried removing "m". And then I also tried [.\r\n\s]

Comment: @DaveStein: Sorry, forgot that you were building the regex from a string. You need `\\s\\S`. I'll update.

Comment: Ah yeah that was totally it. Thanks! So basically my earlier tries I would have also needed to do \\n instead of \n. S works way better though. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveStein: Yeah, if you were explicitly matching a newline character, and if you're creating the regex from a string, you need to escape the  `\ ` since both the String and the RegExp treat the `\ ` as an escape character.

Comment: ...and you really don't need the `m` modifier. That makes the `^` and `$` have a slightly different meaning where they match at the beginning and end of each line, instead of the entire string.

Comment: Yeah I meant to write that and got pulled away from comp. I had taken it away and swapped for the \\s\\S and it worked fine :) Thanks